# How to make a special button with click event?

Tags: silverlight, button, user-controls

I need to make a special control, that IS from different parts. 
So the parts are:

Image

Indicator (like iPhone icon with badge)

So - standart button is not enough for this case - I have to make my own one.

And? I start from grid and make myCustomControl that inherits UserControl.

All is fine, animation works, but...

How can I fire CLICK event from it? Button has this event, UserControl - has no.

Only mouseLeftButtonDown, but as I red - using this event - no good.

So, guys, how can I click event for my UserControl?

Or have I inherit myControl from button?

I tried it, but click_event did not show up in event tab (in Expression Blend 4)

What should I do?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you want your UserControl to raise a Click event, you will have to add it yourself! You can then handle the Click event that the button raises and then raise a Click event from the UserControl.

There are other possibilities - you can host all kinds of content within a button, e.g.

```
<Button>
    <Image Source="image.png"/>
</Button>
```

Could you build your control using a Button?

Comment: "You can then handle the Click event that the button raises"

Comment: There is NO buttons inside my UserControl. No buttons to raise click_event!

Comment: "Could you build your control using a Button?"

Comment: I pursue also educational purposes. Making customControl from scratch. )))